# Get values from JSON array using PHP

Tags: php, json

I run the following PHP after I submit a form and get the output shown below:

```
$data = json_encode($_POST);

// output
{"First_Name":"Fred"}
```

How do I use PHP to just display the value 'Fred'?

I tried `echo $data['First_Name'];` but this is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You no need to encode your incoming `$_POST` data.

Just say:

```
echo $_POST['First_Name'];
```

If you get a `json` data, decode it into an array:

```
$data = '{"First_Name":"Fred"}';
$decoded = json_decode($data, true);
echo $decoded['First_name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't know why you use json_encode on PHP Array, and try to access it like it's an array - because after json_encode it's a string.

You have to use `json_decode($data, true)` and then you can access it like `$data['First_Name']` or try to access it directly without `json_encode()` by `$_POST['First_Name']`

Answer (score 1):

The `json_decode()` function is used to decode or convert a JSON object to a PHP object.And try to put the object to decode in another variable to avoid errors

```
<?php
$obj = '{"First_Name":"Fred"}';
$data = json_decode($obj);
echo ($data->First_Name);
?>
```